# multiple audio fingerprinting python

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, audio-fingerprinting

i want to fingerprint multiple sounds from microphone using python.
here are some of sounds :

```
https://vocaroo.com/i/s0cSkxbfBmh1
https://vocaroo.com/i/s0wnOnAwFofj
https://vocaroo.com/i/s0BL91ehSIwZ
https://vocaroo.com/i/s1QW8h53CIJd
```

i used python dejavu library but it cant recognize multiple sounds that play continuously. (they play continuously)

here is the code i used (from dejavu manual):

```
from dejavu import Dejavu
config = {
    "database": {
         "host": "127.0.0.1",
         "user": "root",
         "passwd": "admin123",
         "db": "dejavu"
     }
 }

djv = Dejavu(config)
from dejavu.recognize import MicrophoneRecognizer
song = djv.recognize(MicrophoneRecognizer, seconds=5)

print (song)
```

but as i said it can recognize only one sound in a run.

thanks

Comment: It is made to recognize one sound at a time, if you want to separate different signals this tool might not be the best for you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you know any other tool to use ?